# Should library expose c_int to consumers or force i32 compatibility

Tags: rust

I'm writing a simple Rust wrapper over C++ library. And this library is written using native `int` type. And I don't know what's the best approach to expose these API via rust. Here we have two considerations:

1. Library is just a wrapper over C++ code and it's not our responsability to check `int` size. Thus, just expose `c_int` in our high level interfaces.
2. High level interfaces *must* use native Rust types such as `i32` so we use it everywhere while statically checking that `int` is `i32` via some healthcheck like

```rust
#[allow(unused)]
fn assert_32_bit() {
    let _: c_int = 0_i32;
}
```

The latter just forbid user to use this library anywhere `int` is not `i32`.

I have read nomicon opinion about this problem ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/ffi.html)), and its opinion is:

> The raw C API needs to be wrapped to provide memory safety and make
>   use of higher-level concepts like vectors.

But all examples with `safe wrappers` are using `int32_t` and similar types, that  are easy to map on `Rust` type system.

Which approach should I take, and why? What's the official community position about this question?

For example, here is sample C++ function:

```cpp
int sum(int a, int b);
```

Should I write

```rust
fn high_level_api_sum(a: c_int, b: c_int) { unsafe {sum(a, b)} }
```

or

```rust
fn high_level_api_sum(a: i32, b: i32) { unsafe {sum(a, b)} }

#[allow(unused)]
fn assert_32_bit() {
    let _: c_int = 0_i32;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `assert_32_bit` -- if you try to compile the `i32`-using wrapper on a platform where `int` is 64 bits, won't that be a compile error by itself?

Comment: @trentcl you are right, but in your case you will get N errors for every place where `i32` is not `c_int`. On the other hand, we can place `assert_32_bit` in one single place, such as `build.rs` and have just one self-descriptive error, before even trying to build anything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there *is* anything remotely like an "official" position on this.  What follows is opinion... perhaps suggesting this question isn't suitable for SO in the first place.

If the correct type is `c_int`, use `c_int`.  Rust programmers shouldn't be so very fragile that they curl into the fetal position just because you use a C type in an interface *to a C/C++ library*.

Ask yourself this: do your users **benefit** from you locking out any and all potential platforms where `c_int` is not `i32` (*e.g.* embedded platforms)?

If the answer is "they don't", then don't do it.  If they *do* benefit somehow, well, you'll have to weigh that against locking out platforms yourself.  Maybe the use of `c_int` imposes some kind of wider interface issue.